# Liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0 Upgradation steps (Windows + Tomcat + MySql)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have taken the backup of my live portal and I want to upgrade it to newer version in localhost and then move the upgraded version to my live site.

I followed the steps in the link http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Upgrade+Instructions+from+5.2+to+6.0. and my stpes are :

1) I have setup the new liferay 6.0 on my localhost 
(successful installation of liferay 6.0 with inbuilt Hypersonic database )

2) I have imported MySql database of live system to the local MySql Server.

3) After stopping the tomcat server, I have changed the configuration file portal-ext.properties for the MySql database details.

4) Then, I have started the start.bat file. It is showing upgrade process well but after few minutes window is closed

Can anyone help me in this regard where I have done some mistake or am I missing something during the upgration. If anyone has some idea then please share their steps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention that you also copy your document library / image gallery folder to the new installation. This typically (unless configured otherwise) sits in your "data" folder. Just importing the MySql database isn't enough, as it contains only the metadata for doclib & image gallery.

You'll have to take this into account for backups also - ideally you'd read about backup and set up a second 5.2.3 instance (and make sure it runs) from your backup, then start upgrading. I typically forbid to call something a backup if nobody ever demonstrated, that they can use it to successfully restore in a completely new environment. This is your chance to ultimately test your backup procedure.

Comment: Please check the following error can you suggest something for this I am installing the liferay setup on my localhost.                                                 ERROR [PortalLDAPImporterImpl:470] Unable to import user CN=XXX ,CN=Users: null:null:{samaccountname=sAMAccountName: XXXX}
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Is this in any way related to the question or my answer? I can't connect both and need some help relating them to each other to get a clue what happens

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your suggestion. Actually I have not copied the images and theme gallery because for time being I just want to check whether the up-gradation is going well with the default theme or not.I have some progress at my end but due to the above mentioned error my up-gradation step is taking time and showing error message. I just want to resolve whatever error is coming so that after up-gradation step with default theme of liferay I will be sure that process is going well then I can look for theme up-gradation etc. I hope my comments are clear otherwise please let me know.

Comment: Image Gallery and Document Library contain more than just theme data - in fact, they are not related to themes at all. I still can't relate your LDAP Import problems stated in the first comment to the original question or my answer. Try the suggestion given in the answer - don't try shortcuts if you're interested in a working update. You can try with the default theme instead of updating the theme as well, but otherwise: Do a backup, restore a separate installation, validate that it works as expected as 5.2.3. Then upgrade your full restored version.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your great support. I will do the needful at my end and in case of any problem I will post here.

Comment: can you please let me know when we have to copy and paste the darta folder before the setup of liferay or after the installation?

Comment: at least before the first start. Setup a restored database, the same with a restored data folder. Then start Liferay for the first time (same version as you backed up) - you should see no difference from your original server. Then upgrade exactly this new installation in place.

Comment: Actually I am working on up-gradation from last 20 days with some hit and trial but still not able to do it successfully 100%. After upgrade step sometime liferay portal run with lots of users are missing in the database and also from next time when I start the tomcat server still it is showing some upgrade message. I have copied document_lib documents already. Is there anything that we have to do with lucene and Jackrabbit folders too check this: http://www.ewernli.com/how-to-upgrade-liferay.  My portal is integrated with active-directories and getting LDAP error too. Please anyone guide me.

Comment: If anyone can share steps for upgrade which was successful at their end it will be great.(Liferay 5.2.3 to Liferay 6.0)