# Upgrading Liferay 5.2 to 6.0 checklist

Tags: liferay, upgrade, liferay-6

I need to make an upgrade of Liferay, as mentioned above(5.2->6.0) So far, as my research ([1](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/official/liferay-administrator-guide-6.0.pdf),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699776/liferay-theme-upgrade-from-5-2-to-6-0),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193725/liferay-5-2-3-to-6-0-upgradation-steps-windows-tomcat-mysql)) shows I need to:

1. Make backups of the Database and file system of plugins (especially `portal*.properties`).
2. Overwrite dependency jars
3. Deploy new .war
4. Set permission algorithm to 5 in the properties (as L-5.2 uses it, however L-6.0 uses 6)
5. Start application,

   - see if the DB updates correctly
   - see if the portal is working correctly
6. Clean up user-specific permissions
7. Convert legacy permission algorithm to 6 in the control Panel
8. [Migrate a custom theme](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Upgrade+Themes+from+5.2.x+to+6.0.x).
9. [Upgrade EXT to EXT Plugin(p. 398)](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/official/liferay-administrator-guide-6.0.pdf)

It's fairly understandable, but I stumbled upon [this thread(Missing FileEntryForm class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260262/using-fileentryform-after-upgrading-from-liferay-5-2-3-to-6-0). Are there any more changes of this kind?

Also, is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using customizations to liferay OOTB portlets in 5.2.3 especially the `Document Library` in 6.0 and `Documents & Media` in 6.1, then everything needs to be re-written as there are a lot of changes to the FileEntry API even from 6.0 to 6.1 there are considerable changes in the FileEntry API. If you will be going through so much change to updgrade to 6.0 I would suggest then better go for 6.1 GA2 since if you have any customizations in the OOTB portlet then again you would have to migrate your code base to 6.1 GA2 & moreover 6.1 GA2 is much better than 6.0.

Comment: But the re-writing would be only with the portlets changing `Document Library`? What about if I wrote my own portlets, without the `FileEntry API`?

Comment: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13927972/468763) specific to your query. Also don't forget to visit the link mentioned in the answer and the [comment by @OlafKock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927914/liferay-6-1-portlet-worked-incorrect-in-5-2-3/13927972#comment19223933_13927972).